# How can I reassign XHR without reloading the page in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is a PHP Bootstrap CODE I try to dynamically change bootstrap modal body content that can I can easily add or edit product category . Then I submit the entered or changed data to save into database by submitting the form through Ajax .
I use pure JavaScript Ajax request to done this job for me.
For the first time when I click into Create Product Category Everything work fine. But when the first time content add then I try to add anther product the second product will automatically add two times it will increase for the forth time and so on .
I know the problem . But I can't solve it.
how can I reassign or how can I Completely clean Ajax after the task done then after clicking to create new product category I will renew Ajax ?
this is my JavaScript Ajax code :

```
// get add category 
document.getElementById('add_category').addEventListener('click', () => {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("GET", 'add.php', true);
    console.log("add_category")
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('exampleModalLabel').innerHTML = 'Create Product Category';
            document.getElementById('modal-body').innerHTML = this.response;
            // console.log(this.response)
            dynamicChangePicture()

            // on change category_name
            onChangeCategoryName('category_name');

            // add new Category
            document.getElementById('save_btn').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log('save_btn')
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('POST', `../includes/functions.php`, true)
                xhr.onload = function() {
                    if (xhr.status == 200) {
                        console.log(xhr.response)

                        if (xhr.response == 'category name add successfully! ') {

                            document.getElementById('close_modal_btn').click();
                            showMessage(xhr.response, 'Add')
                            console.log(xhr.responseText)
                            // document.getElementById('logo_box').innerHTML = `<span class='text-success'>${xhr.response}</span>`;
                        } else {
                            showMessage(xhr.response, 'Remove')
                            document.getElementById('logo_box').innerHTML = `<span class='text-danger'>${xhr.response}</span>`;
                        }


                        setTimeout(() => {
                            document.getElementById('table-body').innerHTML = '';
                            defaultLoad();
                            console.log("data Loaded")
                        }, 5000)
                    }
                }
                const formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('add_category_form'))
                xhr.send(formData);
            })
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
})
```

even I Change inside **xhr** variable  with the a deferent one it will still have the same problem.

Comment: It's because you are adding onclick event listener to the `save_btn` element each time you submit. Don't set any event listeners inside other event listeners, unless it's a newly created element.

Comment: Then how to fix this? @vanowm

Comment: Move it out of the onclick event listener for `add_category`